# "the idea started simple" vs "the idea started simply"

Tags: meaning, adjectives, adverbs, word-order

What is the difference in meaning between the two phrases in the title, and are both gamatically correct?

My impression is the following:

1. "The idea started simple" = In the beginning the idea was simple.
2. "The idea started simply" = It was easy to get the idea started.

Then there is also the following:

3. "The idea simply started" = the idea started *spontaneously*.

Are my impressions correct?

Comment: I'd say (2a) defaults (and I'd agree that there is more than a whiff of illogicality here) to a reasonably common paraphrase of (1a/1b). I'd expect (2b) to be paraphrased rather differently, say 'It was simple to get the idea [widely] accepted. 'Starting an idea' sounds odd. (3a) is certainly the sense you indicate, though 'just' is closer in emphasis.

Comment: I think this is an interesting insight. I think that we always say "started simply" and always mean "started simple," and the question is why we express ourselves in this way. Maybe the problem is like the linking-verb use of words like "looked" or "sounded," where the rhythm of the sentence seems to require an adverb although the grammar seems to require an adjective.